# Checking that a filename does not end with "Com.js"

Tags: javascript, beginner, validation

I'm fairly new to JavaScript  and I wonder if there is a way to write this function shorter and better?

```
   function checkFile(file){       
        var cbEnab= true;
        if (file !== undefined && file !== null) {
            cbEnab = (!jQuery.endsWith(file, "Com.js"));
        }
        return cbEnab;
    }
```

Comment: I'm only a beginner of sorts in Javascript myself, but I believe you could write the evaluation as `if (!file)`. Also, the bracers around the definition of `cbEnab` seem unnecessary, don't they?

Comment: @IvoCoumans `if (!file)` would work, but changes the behavior a bit. Eliminating braces would also work, but it's poor programming practice.

Comment: I actually meant the parentheses `()`, not the curly braces `{}`. Didn't know that `!file` would be different!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By mechanical transformation, I arrive at:

```
function checkFile(file) {
    return file == null || !jQuery.endsWith(file, "Com.js");
}
```

The use of `===` strict equality checking is not necessary; [`==` lumps `null` and `undefined` together](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/).

I have my doubts about the whole function, though, as the function name gives no indication that it's going to check whether its argument ends in `"Com.js"`.

Comment: Thanks but do you see that if the file is null I provided true as defulat ,so Im not sure that your code cover this...

Comment: @shopiaT Why are you unsure?